# Как вывести связанные таблицы Django API

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

Как вывести связанные таблицы Django API?

Вот модели:

```html
class VehicleBrands(models.Model):
    Name = models.TextField(verbose_name="Name", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name


class VehicleModels(models.Model):
    VehicleBrandId = models.ForeignKey(VehicleBrands, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='VehicleModels',
                                       blank=True, null=True)
    Name = models.TextField(verbose_name="Name", blank=True, null=True)
    ModelNumber = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="ModelNumber", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

Serialiser

```html
class VehicleModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    VehicleBrandId = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='VehicleBrandId.Name')

    class Meta:
        model = VehicleModels
        fields = [
            'id',
            'VehicleBrandId',
            'Name',
            'ModelNumber',
        ]


class VehicleBrandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Name = VehicleModelSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = VehicleBrands
        fields = ['id', 'Name']
```

View:

```html
class BrandModelList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = VehicleBrands.objects.prefetch_related()
    serializer_class = serializers.VehicleBrandSerializer
```

urls.py

```html
router.register('model', BrandModelList, basename='id')
```

Но в ответ приходят пустые значения:

```html
{
    "id": 74363,
    "Name": [
        {
            "Name": null,
            "ModelNumber": null
        },
        {
            "Name": null,
            "ModelNumber": null
        },
        {
            "Name": null,
            "ModelNumber": null
        },
        {
            "Name": null,
            "ModelNumber": null
        },
        {
            "Name": null,
            "ModelNumber": null
        },
        {
            "Name": null,
            "ModelNumber": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Не понимаю, таблицу вроде выводит нужную, но почему значения null

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй написать:

```
class VehicleBrandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       Name = VehicleModelSerializer(many=True)
       ...
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]